# Query syntax with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

users

`userid | pseudo`

posts

`id | titre`

posts_com

`id | userid | id_billet | auteur | date | html`

I need to list the lasts posts_com with their post id owner and user owner... I tryied this query but the results are not corrects... Any idea please?

```
SELECT c.userid,
       c.id_billet,
       c.auteur,
       c.date,
       c.html,
       u.pseudo,
       b.titre,
       b.id
FROM posts_com AS c,
     users AS u,
     posts AS b
WHERE u.userid=b.userid
ORDER BY c.id DESC
LIMIT 12
```

[EDIT]
I need :

-> comment 1 (html) from auteur on post titre (user foo)

-> comment 2 (html) from auteur2 on post titre2 (user foo2)
...

Comment: In what way are "*the results not correct*"?  You appear to be missing join criteria for the `posts_com` table (i.e. how that table relates to the others).

Comment: posts table doesn't seem to have a userid column

Comment: Show your desired results

Comment: it displays same id_billet, same date, same html and wrong titre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use join

```
SELECT A.userid,A.id_billet,A.auteur,A.date,A.html,B.pseudo,C.id,C.titre
FROM posts_com A
JOIN users B ON A.userid = B.userid
JOIN posts C ON A.id = C.id
ORDER BY A.id DESC
LIMIT 12
```

**EDIT**

```
SELECT A.userid,A.id_billet,A.auteur,A.date,A.html,B.pseudo,C.id,C.titre
FROM posts_com A
JOIN users B ON A.userid = B.userid
JOIN posts C ON A.id_billet = C.id
ORDER BY A.id DESC
LIMIT 12
```

Comment: Ok, it works with `ON A.id_billet = C.id` instead of `ON A.id = C.id`! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

line

```
WHERE u.userid=b.userid
```

There doesn't seem to be a column named userid in table posts. Maybe you mean

```
WHERE u.userid=b.id
```

?

Comment: I assume that the id column in post_com is the post-id, since it also has a userid column

Answer (score 0):

You have not linked the post_com table to your resultset. Therefore all records of post_com are joined with all records of your userse-post join.

```
SELECT c.userid,
       c.id_billet,
       c.auteur,
       c.date,
       c.html,
       u.pseudo,
       b.titre,
       b.id
FROM posts_com AS c,
     users AS u,
     posts AS b
WHERE u.userid=b.userid
  AND b.id = c.id(+)
ORDER BY c.id DESC
LIMIT 12
```

Answer (score 0):

first you need to use JOINs, and 2ndly your table structure is not clear I mean there is no notable relation between posts_com and posts table, we don't know if posts_com.id = posts.id OR posts_com.userid = posts.id or posts_com.id_billet = posts.id?

```
SELECT c.userid,
       c.id_billet,
       c.auteur,
       c.date,
       c.html,
       u.pseudo,
       b.titre,
       b.id
FROM (posts_com c JOIN users u
       ON c.userid = u.userid
     ) JOIN posts b
       ON c.id_billet = b.id
ORDER BY c.id DESC
LIMIT 12
```

Comment: I guess posts.id refer to id_billet in posts_com, please clear if not. answer updated